# Distinguish between user logout and session expired logout (SSH and web console)

Tags: bash, centos, logout, syslog, openssh

we are searching for a solution to log an event (for example into the syslog) when a user logs out of the system. This could be logging out from a shell (bash) or logging out using ssh. We want to distinguish between explicit user logouts via "exit" and users sessions which just expire (timeout). Is that possible? How-to? Which directions to look for a solution?

The system is RHEL7/CentOS7 and runs using VMWare (web console logout should also be logged).

Comment: Maybe I can use wtmp?

Comment: See proposed solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502915/differentiate-between-exit-and-session-timeout covering same question without the ssh

Answer (score 1):

You might need too different solutions.

- For normal sessions, which will have a login event, you can set a trap on the 'EXIT' event. This will cover explicit logout (CTRL/D, or exit), gettng killed by signal (NOT signal 9), and timeout. Look for bash 'trap' command. Those can be set at the loginn startup script (bashrc)
- For SSH sessions, setting the remote 'bashrc' will make it possible to capture end of session (including timeout, signal).

**EDIT**

It's possible to get indication of 'TIMEOUT' by checking '$?' in the TRAP handler. It will be 142 corresponding to ALRM signal (kill -l 142=ARLM). This is not explicitly document, but is consistent with the default signal handler for kill -ALRM.

```
function my_trap {
  local X=$1
  if [ "$X" = "$(kill -l ALRM)" ] ; then
     Log Timeout
  else
     Log Exit/EOF
  fi
}

trap 'my_trap $?' EXIT
```

Comment: How to differentiate in the suggested solutions between an exit due to timeout and an exit due to explicit user logout? I need 2 different log messages for these cases.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting the same output for explicit user logout and an expired session. In both cases $? equals 0. "$(kill -l ALRM)" is 14.

Comment: Using strace you can clearly see that the exit code is also 0 when there is a timeout. --- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=5141, si_uid=0} ---
timed out waiting for input: auto-logout
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x456b00, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f844493d3f0}, {0x456b00, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f844493d3f0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD TSTP TTIN TTOU], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++