# Differentiate between exit and session timeout

Tags: linux, bash, audit

I have the following requierements:

- produce audit log when bash session has been terminated by the user (exit)
- produce audit log when bash session has timed out

Those audit logs must be different. I am playing around with the following script `trap.sh`:

```
export TMOUT=10

function handle-timeout {
    echo "Timeout"
}

function handle-exit {
    echo "Exit"
}

trap handle-exit EXIT
```

Now if I do:

```
valegon@precision ~ (master) $ bash
valegon@precision ~ (master) $ source trap.sh
valegon@precision ~ (master) $ exit
Exit
```

It works as expected. If instead, I wait for the timeout to happen:

```
valegon@precision ~ (master) $ bash
valegon@precision ~ (master) $ source trap.sh
valegon@precision ~ (master) $ timed out waiting for input: auto-logout
Exit
```

There are two problems here:

1. the timeout is triggering EXIT, which I do not want
2. I do not know how to trap the timeout specifically

How can I solve these open issues?

Comment: I don't think this is doable without cooperation from the invoking process. Bash doesn't have timeouts; it is handled by the process which started Bash (I'm guessing SSH though there are possibly other mechanisms I am overlooking ... Telnet if you are time traveling here from the 1980s).

Comment: @tripleee. Bash has timeouts, from the manual: `TMOUT  If  set  to  a value greater than zero, TMOUT is treated as the default timeout for the read builtin.  The select command terminates if input does not arrive after TMOUT seconds when input is coming from a terminal.  In an interactive shell, the value is interpreted as the number of seconds to wait for a line of input after issuing the primary prompt.  Bash terminates after waiting for that number of seconds if a complete line of input does not arrive.`

Comment: Yeah, true, but I still believe you are *actually* experiencing a timeout in the session layer, in the parent process which is running Bash.

Comment: @tripleee: not at all. Without sourcing the `traph.sh` no timeout happens. The parent process is not involved.

Comment: I looked at the [code in `eval.c`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/d233b485e83c3a784b803fb894280773f16f2deb/eval.c#L315) and it does not seem to differentiate the `exit` event in any way. It uses `SIGALRM` internally but `trap '...' ALRM` doesn't do anything useful for me (Bash 3.x on MacOS).

Comment: @tripleee thanks, good hint. I am also not able to find anything there to implement my requirements. `ALRM` gets processed by bash itself I assume, in order to implement the timeout.

Comment: Note that bash capture the ALRM signal into the exit code, so that the trap handler can examine '$?'.  See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2nd Attempt**

Based on feedback, previous solution using trap on EXIT does not work well. Alternative, based on using PROMPT_COMMAND seems to give better mileage.

Basic Logic:

- Capture command prompt time - start)
- At 'exit' event, check if (now-start) > TMOUT
- Normally, exit, CTRL/D, etc will finish in 1-2 seconds.

```
#! /bin/bash
function pre_cmd {
        START=$SECONDS
}

function log_exit {
    if [ "$((SECONDS-START-TMOUT))" -ge 0 ] ; then
       echo "TIMEOUT"
    else
       echo "Normal Exit"
    fi
}

TMOUT=15
PROMPT_COMMAND=pre_cmd
trap 'log_exit' EXIT
```

Comment: Great idea! Tried and works like a charm. Also detects killing of the bash process as a "Normal Exit" (which is fine for me)

Answer (score 1):

Same as [Distinguish between user logout and session expired logout (SSH and web console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58501165/distinguish-between-user-logout-and-session-expired-logout-ssh-and-web-console)

I'm posting the same answer that I've posted there.

...

For normal sessions, which will have a login event, you can set a trap on the 'EXIT' event. This will cover explicit logout (CTRL/D, or exit), gettng killed by signal (NOT signal 9), and timeout. Look for bash 'trap' command. Those can be set at the loginn startup script (bashrc)

**EDIT**

It's possible to get indication of 'TIMEOUT' by checking '$?' in the TRAP handler. It will be 142 corresponding to ALRM signal (kill -l 142=ARLM). This is not explicitly document, but is consistent with the default signal handler for kill -ALRM.

```
function my_trap {
  local X=$1
  if [ "$X" = "$(kill -l ALRM)" ] ; then
     Log Timeout
  else
     Log Exit/EOF
  fi
}

trap 'my_trap $?' EXIT
```

Comment: Unfortunately the exit value is always 0, both in case of exit and in case of timeout. Easy to test in a sub-bash (to avoid getting kicked-out completely) by sourcing your implementation and setting TMOUT=10

Comment: You are correct, I've tested the code with explicit 'read' statement (TMOUT=5 ; read ...), and it was detectable with $? 142. Need to test timeout at the prompt

Comment: Let me know if you get a different result.