# Access console contents

Tags: linux, bash, audit

Is if possible for a running bash session to access the contents of the console, as-is?

I would like to collect the whole console contents when the bash session is terminated, in order to perform some audit activities.

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about *writing code*. This is a better fit for [unix.se].

Comment: ...that said, when you say "the whole console contents", do you mean scrollback, not just what's displayed at the moment? It *might* be possible to grab current content from the TTY or PTY device, but scrollback is the domain of the terminal program. Honestly, you'll have a much better time of it if you control the terminal, if only by putting a fake terminal in between the user's "real" terminal program and the running application (thus, `screen`, `tmux`, or even `script`)

Comment: But I wouldn't use any of those as security controls; anything that runs as the same user you want to log actions of can be subverted by that user. It's far more surefire to run something out-of-process that records the actual syscalls writing to or reading from the TTY; sysdig, eBPF, etc. provide tools more fit to task, hooking into kernel events and getting a log streamed that no user-owned applications need to voluntarily participate in.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My real goal is to detect a bash timeout (and **only** a bash timeout, no other exit conditions are of interest to me). I haven't found any way of detecting that condition, so what I am thinking about is to react to the only reliable indication that a timeout occurred, which is a bash generated message (on the console): `timed out waiting for input: auto-logout`. Relevant bash code is here: https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/d233b485e83c3a784b803fb894280773f16f2deb/eval.c#L315

Comment: The question and the actual goal are... rather distant from each other. Personally, I'd install a modified copy of bash, if that's what you really intend to do -- add a hook that triggers on `TMOUT` and you can touch a file or do some other easy-to-check-for action; make the solution general enough and perhaps it'll be accepted upstream.

Comment: (But then, I run NixOS, a distro that makes it trivial to install several different, potentially-separately-patched, copies of the same tool alongside each other, so I'm coming from a world where applying a patch to the copy of bash used for users' interactive shells doesn't need to change the copy of bash used as a shebang for executing scripts or such, so patching is much safer).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes I thought about that too (modifying bash). I will maybe give it a try. Regarding NixOS: I was in a presentation about it 5 years ago, but I have not yet been able to give it a try. The idea seems nice though. Do you have any introductory resource for me? BTW, my current issue will be probably solved by going this route: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58510716/10895273

Comment: Oh, nice -- that's a very clever answer. I don't have particular pointers re: getting started on NixOS, and I'll admit that there's still a learning curve -- it took me a few months to be fully comfortable with the Nix language, and I came in already having some functional programming background.

Answer (score 0):

One common solution to achieve auditing is to use the logging options of sudo. It allows capturing tty input and/or output, and also include tools for replaying.

One advantage of sudo is that it is running outside the user control (sudo is a setuid program), which will prevent the users from being able to disable the auditing.

Applying the solution will require changing the login shell of the users.

Another alternative is 'auditd' and 'sudosh'. For older systems, sudosh is easier to implement.

Comment: The requirement is to implement a bash-only solution, without relying on other tools.